# How to run a saved query against another Stack Exchange site in Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I have a saved query to find the percentage of self-answered questions (no restriction on self-accepted) on Data Explorer.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1115/self-answered-questions

How do I run that against another site?  I tried

https://data.stackexchange.com/metastackoverflow/s/1115/self-answered-questions

And it gave an ugly runtime error.  (This is a bug, no?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it's https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1115/self-answered-questions

(Protip: You can click on the little site icons)

Answer (score 3):

Yep, there are little site icons one for the main site and one for the meta.

**Note** : User IDs are not the same for Stackoverflow and meta. Go to your profile see your id in the url, its different for each site.

Comment: +1 for the userid thing, even though I already know that