# Show softer error messages on Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Related to [How to run a saved query against another Stack Exchange site in Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83395/156011)
Also to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53095/156011

Is it OK to give runtime errors instead of some more friendly message like `Page not found`?

---

---

## Server Error in '/' Application.

---

### Runtime Error

etc...

Comment: HTTP Error 500: *Hey, baby... Why ya gotta hurt me? You know I'd do anything for you, but I just can't do that!*

Comment: If you submit a patch I promise to pull it in :)

Answer (score 3):

I have added in some 404 handling for users and queries (and also some 301 redirects based off the friendly titles).