# Page doesn't exist handling on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, 404-not-found

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Show softer error messages on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83399/show-softer-error-messages-on-data-explorer)

Typically when I type into a browser address at data.stackexchange.com, e.g. https://data.stackexchange.com/xxx I get a nice error page.

However for the address https://data.stackexchange.com/xxx/queries I get raw error from IIS. It doesn't matter what I put instead of "xxx."